# Pandas groupby with delimiter join

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I tried to use groupby to group rows with multiple values.

```
col val
A  Cat
A  Tiger
B  Ball
B  Bat

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Inputfile.txt", sep='\t')
group = df.groupby(['col'])['val'].sum()
```

I got

```
A CatTiger
B BallBat
```

I want to introduce a delimiter, so that my output looks like

```
A Cat-Tiger
B Ball-Bat
```

I tried,

```
group = df.groupby(['col'])['val'].sum().apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x))
```

this yielded,

```
A C-a-t-T-i-g-e-r
B B-a-l-l-B-a-t
```

What is the issue here ?

Thanks,

AP

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alternatively you can do it this way:

```
In [48]: df.groupby('col')['val'].agg('-'.join)
Out[48]:
col
A    Cat-Tiger
B     Ball-Bat
Name: val, dtype: object
```

---

**UPDATE:** answering question from the comment:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
  col    val
0   A    Cat
1   A  Tiger
2   A  Panda
3   B   Ball
4   B    Bat
5   B  Mouse
6   B    Egg

In [3]: df.groupby('col')['val'].agg('-'.join)
Out[3]:
col
A       Cat-Tiger-Panda
B    Ball-Bat-Mouse-Egg
Name: val, dtype: object
```

Last for convert index or MultiIndex to columns:

```
df1 = df.groupby('col')['val'].agg('-'.join).reset_index(name='new')
```

Comment: Does this work when joining more than two rows together at a time? I tried this using a new line character to join rows, the result is that the first two rows are joined with a new line, the rest are concatenated together without a delimiter.

Comment: Added `reset_index`, because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57712554/groupby-several-pandas-columns-merge-and-comma-separate-values-in-other-column), be free modify answer.

Answer (score 6):

just try

```
group = df.groupby(['col'])['val'].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x))
```