# Pandas - clubbing data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have input excel like below..

```
InvoiceNo  Des
123        A B C
123        L M N 
789        S V T
789        Q P R
```

How to get output like

```
InvoiceNo  Des
123        A B C, L M N
789        S V T, Q P R
```

Comment: Need `df.groupby('InvoiceNo')['Des'].agg(', '.join).reset_index()`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44368537/pandas-groupby-with-delimiter-join