# Separate aggregated ints with semicolons as a string, instead of a list

Tags: python, excel, pandas

**Update down below!**

I am trying to merge and sort a list of IDs and their connected unique Name_ID, separated by semicolons.
For example:

```
Name_ID Adress_ID            Name_ID Adress_ID
Name1   5875383              Name1   5875383; 5901847
Name1   5901847              Name2   5285200
Name2   5285200      to      Name3   2342345; 6463736
Name3   2342345
Name3   6463736
```

This is my current code:

```
origin_file_path = Path("Folder/table.xlsx")
dest_file_path = Path("Folder/table_sorted.xlsx")

table = pd.read_excel(origin_file_path)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(table)

df1 = df1.groupby('Name_ID').agg(lambda x: x.tolist())

df1.to_excel(dest_file_path, sheet_name="Adress_IDs")
```

But it exports it like this to the excel file:

```
Name_ID Adress_ID
Name1   [5875383, 5901847]
```

I couldn't find a way to tell pandas that it should be something other than a list or formatted differently. I also am not sure if it would be a good Idea to use something like openpyxl to edit it afterwards.

Can someone tell me what the best way would be to get rid of the list format and separate by semicolons instead of commas?

**UPDATE:**
The user [Jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) linked me this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44368537/pandas-groupby-with-delimiter-join). But I can't seem to be able to combine `';'.join` with `lambda x: x.tolist()`.

```
df1 = df1.groupby('Kartenname').agg(';'.join, lambda x: x.tolist())
```

> Produces TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

```
df1 = df1.groupby('Kartenname').agg(lambda x: x.tolist(), ';'.join)
```

> Produces TypeError: () takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.

I also tried other Combinations but none seem to even execute properly. Getting rid of the lambda function isn't an option because then it just pastes Name_ID Adress_ID a thousand times instead of the correct Name and correct IDs.

Comment: @Trenton_M Dupe was changed. If not changed, you are 100% right.

Comment: The OP asked the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58179593/how-to-combine-join-and-lambda-x-x-tolist-inside-an-groupby-agg-functio.  So this is a duplicate and should be closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine ';'.join and lambda x: x.tolist() inside an groupby.agg() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58179593/how-to-combine-join-and-lambda-x-x-tolist-inside-an-groupby-agg-functio)