# How to combine ';'.join and lambda x: x.tolist() inside an groupby.agg() function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

**Update down below!**

I am trying to merge and sort a list of IDs and their connected unique Name_ID, separated by semicolons.
For example:

```
Name_ID Adress_ID            Name_ID Adress_ID
Name1   5875383              Name1   5875383; 5901847
Name1   5901847              Name2   5285200
Name2   5285200      to      Name3   2342345; 6463736
Name3   2342345
Name3   6463736
```

This is my current code:

```
origin_file_path = Path("Folder/table.xlsx")
dest_file_path = Path("Folder/table_sorted.xlsx")

table = pd.read_excel(origin_file_path)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(table)

df1 = df1.groupby('Name_ID').agg(lambda x: x.tolist())

df1.to_excel(dest_file_path, sheet_name="Adress_IDs")
```

But it exports it like this to the excel file:

```
Name_ID Adress_ID
Name1   [5875383, 5901847]
```

Can someone tell me what the best way would be to get rid of the list format and separate by semicolons instead of commas?

**Update:**

The user [Jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) linked me this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44368537/pandas-groupby-with-delimiter-join). But I can't seem to be able to combine `';'.join` with `lambda x: x.tolist()`.

```
df1 = df1.groupby('Kartenname').agg(';'.join, lambda x: x.tolist())
```

> Produces TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

```
df1 = df1.groupby('Kartenname').agg(lambda x: x.tolist(), ';'.join)
```

> Produces TypeError: () takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.

I also tried other Combinations but none seem to even execute properly. Getting rid of the lambda function isn't an option because then it just pastes Name_ID Adress_ID a thousand times instead of the correct Name and correct IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass to `agg` function tuples with new column names with aggregate functions:

```
df['Adress_ID'] = df['Adress_ID'].astype(str)
df1 = df.groupby('Name_ID')['Adress_ID'].agg([('a', ';'.join),
                                              ('b',  lambda x: x.tolist())])

print (df1)
                       a                   b
Name_ID                                     
Name1    5875383;5901847  [5875383, 5901847]
Name2            5285200           [5285200]
Name3    2342345;6463736  [2342345, 6463736]
```

If pass only aggregate functions in list (no tuples) get default columns names:

```
df2 = df.groupby('Name_ID')['Adress_ID'].agg([ ';'.join,lambda x: x.tolist()])

print (df2)
                    join          <lambda_0>
Name_ID                                     
Name1    5875383;5901847  [5875383, 5901847]
Name2            5285200           [5285200]
Name3    2342345;6463736  [2342345, 6463736]
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to make sure the `Address_ID` is `string`

then you can apply this func:

```
df.groupby('Name_ID').agg(lambda x: ':'.join(list(x.values)))
```

more about `'str'.join` [method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp)

Answer (score 0):

- The main issue

  - Can't `join` an `int`

```py
Name_ID  Adress_ID
  Name1    5875383
  Name1    5901847
  Name2    5285200
  Name3    2342345
  Name3    6463736

def fix_my_stuff(x):
    x = x.tolist()
    x = '; '.join([str(y) for y in x])
    return(x)

df_updated = df.groupby('Name_ID').agg(lambda x: fix_my_stuff(x)).reset_index()
print(df_updated)

Name_ID         Adress_ID
  Name1  5875383; 5901847
  Name2           5285200
  Name3  2342345; 6463736
```