# python pandas dataframe color the text as red, green or black in column based on the condition from the other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
ID  CNTS    neg pos neu comp    Overall
1   Reliance Jio Infocomm has accused Bharti Airtel, Vodafone Idea and BSNL of 'cheating' by fraudulently masquerading landline numbers as mobile numbers to unfairly earn interconnect revenue.    0.081   0   0.919   -0.296  Negative
1   The accusation adds new twist to the ongoing telecom tussle.    0.182   0   0.818   -0.25   Negative
1   Here's what is making India's richest man angry.    0.26    0.268   0.472   0.0258  Neutral
2   Jio wants Trai to slap the heaviest penalties on both rivals & BSNL for flouting rules, which it claims cost the company hundreds of crores.    0   0.065   0.935   0.1531  Positive
2   It has also sought a refund of the termination charges it had paid the incumbents due to the alleged fraud. 0.258   0   0.742   -0.7096 Negative
2   Jio claims Airtel, Vodafone Idea and BSNL have implemented a process under which various enterprises are offered mobile numbers as their customer care or helpline numbers. 0   0.118   0.882   0.4939  Positive
```

Also I wrote a function which returns the specific color based on the values of the dataframe column name "Overall":

```
def cts(val):
    if (val == 'Negative'):
        color = 'red'
    elif (val == "Positive"):
        color = 'green'
    else: 
        color = 'black'

    return 'color: %s' % color
```

Now what I want to do that, using the color, the text in the column "CNTS" should get formatted accordingly.

I was trying something which I read on Pandas documentation site:

```
# Apply color
s = df.style.applymap(cts)
s
```

But it obviously threw an error.
But I don't have any clue or idea how I could apply the function to achieve what I wanted to have as.
Could someone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom function with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for filling column by dictionary of colors:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Overall':['Negative','Positive','Another'],
                   'CNT':list('abc')})

def cts(x):
    c1 = 'color: red'
    c2 = 'color: green'
    d = {'Negative':c1, 'Positive':c2}

    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)


    df1['CNT'] = x['Overall'].map(d).fillna('color: black')
    return df1

df.style.apply(cts, axis=None)
```

**Sample**:

[image: pic]

Comment: hey Jez, thanks for helping but I wanted to color CNTS column. :(

Comment: hey Jez - how to groupby ID and get the concatenated text on styler format? I wanted to have an HTML output that has groupby ID, concat text with red, green black color as what we got in above solution.

Comment: @loveR - Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44368537/pandas-groupby-with-delimiter-join)

Comment: I tried this `def color_the_sentences(x):
    c1 = 'color: red'
    c2 = 'color: green'
    d = {'Negative':c1, 'Positive':c2}
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)

    df1['Conv_Sentence'] = x['Overall'].map(d).fillna('color: black')
    
    print(df1['Conv_Sentence'])
    
    df2 = df1.groupby('Conversation_ID')['Conv_Sentence'].agg('-'.join).reset_index(name='Conv_Sentence_1')
    
    return df2` but it threw error: `Result of <function color_the_sentences at 0x0000028EE5F92558> must have identical index and columns as the input`

Comment: @loveR - hmmm, I think it cannot use this way

Comment: @loveR - You have to use `df = df.groupby('Conversation_ID')['Conv_Sentence'].agg('-'.join).reset_index(name='Conv_Sentence_1')` and then `df.style.apply(cts, axis=None)`