# Combine 2 labels into single label in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multilabels as below:

```
 text   label
0   apple   a
1   apple   b
2   orange  o
3   orange  o
4   grapes  o
5   grapes  g
```

Expected output:

```
text    label
0   apple   ab
1   orange  o
2   orange  o
3   grapes  og
```

I tried df.groupby('label')['text']=='apple' but fail.
I tried df[(df.label=='a') & (df.label=='b')] which also fail.
How to select and rename the labels?

Comment: Can you explain `orange  o` in output for prevent wrong answers?

Comment: Possible dupe [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44368537/pandas-groupby-with-delimiter-join)

Answer (score 2):

```
df['label'] = df.groupby('text')['label'].transform(lambda x: ''.join(x) if len(set(x))>1 else x)
df.loc[(df.groupby('text').cumcount()==0) | (df.label.str.len()==1)]
```

Output

```
    text    label
0   apple   ab
2   orange  o
3   orange  o
4   grapes  og
```

Answer (score 0):

Use groupby and agg

```
dfagg = df.groupby('text',as_index=False).agg({'label':lambda x: x.nunique()})[lambda x:x['label']>1]
pd.concat([df[df['text'].isin(dfagg.text)].groupby('text',as_index=False).agg({'label':'sum'}),df[~df['text'].isin(dfagg.text)]])
```

Comment: So miss 2 rows in expected output `orange  o`

Comment: @MhDG7.. I get this error:AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'label'

Comment: I am trying to resolve the issue @jezrael. mentioned. I will update the answer soon

Comment: @MhDG7.. your answer also aggregates the 'o' label which has to be retained untouched