# How to combine values in a dataframe pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below dataframe

[image]

Is there anyway we can combine values in column (Fruit) with respect to values in other two columns and get below result using pandas
[image]

Comment: `df.groupby(['SellerName','SellerID'])['Fruit'].agg(','.join).reset_index()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas groupby with delimiter join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44368537/pandas-groupby-with-delimiter-join)

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby_agg`. If you have other columns, expand the dict with another functions if needed (max, min, first, last, ... or lambda)

```
out = df.groupby(['SellerName', 'SellerID'], as_index=False).agg({'Fruit': ', '.join})
print(out)

# Output
  SellerName  SellerID                   Fruit
0        Rob       200          Apple, Bannana
1      Scott       201  Apple, Kiwi, Pineapple
```

Input dataframe:

```
>>> df
  SellerName  SellerID      Fruit
0        Rob       200      Apple
1      Scott       201      Apple
2        Rob       200    Bannana
3      Scott       201       Kiwi
4      Scott       201  Pineapple
```